# product price for customer group

Tags: php, magento

I hope someone can help me with this, I am trying to extract the product prices from magento based on customer group.

I am not using tier pricing, I simply have a product with a standard price and I have specified different prices for each customer group. For some reason I have been unable to extract this information.

I can see that the price mappings seems to be held in the table 'catalog_product_index_group_price' so I guess I could write direct SQL to extract these but I would much rather use the PHP Mage model to do this, or the V2 SOAP API.

I have tried many methods, currently im using something like below, but without success the price variable is always empty.

```
$rules = Mage::getResourceModel('catalogrule/rule');

$price = $rules->getRulePrice($now, $websiteId, $customer_group_id, $productID);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
$groupPrices = $product->getData('group_price')
```

$groupPrices should now be an array with the data you are looking for.

Comment: Thank You! this worked a treat - bar a very slight modification (i didnt need the 'new' keyword. My code is below for anyone else who might want it. It reads the product id from the request and returns the prices for each customer group                                       <?php

include_once '../App/Mage.php';

 Mage::app();
 
$productID = $_GET["id"];
 
$pd = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productID);
$groupPrices = $pd->getData('group_price');
echo json_encode($groupPrices);
 
?>

Comment: Of course you're right with the `new` keyword. Sorry for that mistake. I corrected that.

Answer (score 0):

the code didnt format well in the comment so here it is again!

```
<?php

include_once '../App/Mage.php';

 Mage::app();

$productID = $_GET["id"];

$pd = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productID);
$groupPrices = $pd->getData('group_price');
echo json_encode($groupPrices);

?>
```